# Does it make sense to poll `pthread_mutex_trylock`?

Tags: locking, pthreads, real-time

Consider a multicore system with two threads running: thread A and thread B, which share some data. Thread A needs to do its job as fast as possible so we want it to be awake as often as possible.

Using spinlocks (either *pthread*'s or implemented on top of atomic primitives) is discarded because we prefer thread B to sleep when waiting to get the lock.

Would it be an acceptable solution to mix busy wait (spin-lock) and "sleepy wait" the following way?:

```cpp
pthread_mutex_t mutex; // Already initialized somewhere
SharedData data; // Structure for interthread communication

// Thread A (high throughput needed => spin)
while (appRunning) {
    while (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) != 0) { } // Controversial point
    // Read/write to data
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

// Thread B (should sleep during wait => standard locking)
while (appRunning) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // Read/write to data
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

PS: I've tried to be generic, but if it matters, the actual scenario is that thread A is filling low-latency audio buffers according to what thread B asks for via the shared data and writes there some results. Thread B reacts to user input and it's acceptable for it to take a while to react as long as thread A doesn't underrun.

Comment: Why not? Did you try it? Did it work? Unless POSIX spec says its undefined (unlikely), it seems to meet your need and thus is justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lock (mutex or spin lock) is not the right solution for low latency scenarios.
It'd be best if you could share only a small amount of data, and then you could just exchange the data in a single atomic instruction.
Another solution is to have 2 data instances and exchange the pointer to it.
If the above cannot work for you, and you have to fallback to a mutex or spin lock, you should prefer a spin lock.
With a spin lock the wake up time will be shorter as you don't have a context switch.
Thread A will have to wait (spinning) when thread B is holding the lock. And you can limit thread B to not acquiring the lock too often.
Thread B can try acquire the lock, not more than once in so often, and sleep for a bit if it fails.

Comment: If I didn't use locks and chose to use exchange via atomic primitives, I'd need to place pertinent explciit memory barries, wouldn't I?

Comment: Basically yes, but on x86, or x86_64, no.
 Instructions with the lock prefix are implicitely memory barriers, but also, with the x86 memory model it's enough to have a compiler barrier. That is asm volatile ("":::"memory"), that is already there with all atomics.